# Unable to ping Windows Cluster's IP and unable to connect listener IP

Tags: sql-server, windows, networking, failovercluster, alwayson

I'm using windows server 2012R2, recently I created a WSFC with 2nodes,Both nodes are in same subnet and assigned a static IP for the cluster. But I can ping the cluster's IP only from the current node, even the node2 and other servers which are in the same subnet are unable to ping.

Because I need this cluster for SQL server alwayson, But I can able to create an Availability group and listener.But the listener IP **unable to ping also I tried telnet from secondary server is also not working**.

My Problem is I want to access the listen from any  servers which are in the same subnet.

Comment: Where are you trying to deploy this cluster?  AWS? Azure?

Comment: I resolved this, anyhow thanks for your response.

Comment: Hi @SQLadmin, i have the same issue and couldn't find a work around yet. What was the reason of your problem ?

Comment: Are you using AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I resolved it.

> NOTE: I was using AWS EC2 instance to configure this,So this solution
>   will work only on AWS. Not sure about Azure or GCP or on-prem.

I have 2 windows servers.

- VPC Range: 10.0.0.0/16
- Server 1: 10.0.0.1
- Server 2: 10.0.0.2

Once the cluster has been configured I have set the cluster IP as

- Cluster IP: 10.0.0.3

Then configured SQL Server Listener. Its a single subnet listener.

- So Listener IP: 10.0.0.4

Now, Just take a [look at this Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_DHCP_Options.html#AmazonDNS).

By default all the routes are going to via **10.0.0.1.** While trying to connect the cluster, I just oped the all traffic to the *10.0.0.0/16* on the both server's security group. For listener it'll try to search the 10.0.0.4 on AWS side, but none of the  instances had this IP.

As per my understanding It'll try to lookup on the AWS network level. So I have added the secondary IP to the current master, then it worked. `But during the failover again it'll fail. So I used multi subnet.` Primary is in Subnet 1, secondary is in Subnet 2. Then while creating the listener it'll ask 2 IP addresses.

**EG:**

- Subnet 1: 10.0.0.0/24
- Listener IP: 10.0.0.4
- Subnet 2: 10.0.1.0/24
- Listener IP: 10.0.1.4

Then attached the 10.0.0.4 as a secondary IP for Server 1, 10.0.1.4 for Server 2.